# Mongodb Aggegrate -unwind and then group(Find unique count)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

I have data stored in this format . I want to find unique msisdn on date .ie., count on unique msisdn on date

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e551b2e63a0f1fc55f026dd"),
    "dateHour" : "2020-02-25 13",
    "detail" : [
        {
            "campaignId" : "5e4a937b459418737cc1dfa5",
            "timestamp" : "2020-02-25 13:03:626",
            "msisdn" : "050920305373677038659253736080036024-1582133696781",
            
        },
        {
            "campaignId" : "5e4a937b459418737cc1dfa5",
            "timestamp" : "2020-02-2025 13:04:626",
            "msisdn" : "050920305373677038659253736080036024-1582133696781",
            
        },
        {
            "campaignId" : "5e4a937b459418737cc1dfa5",
            "timestamp" : "2020-02-25 13:06:626",
            "msisdn" : "050920305373677038659253-1582133696781",
            
        }
        
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you need to find unique by combination of `msisdn` and `timestamp`?

Comment: I need to find unique msisdn on date like on date 2020-02-25 :number of unique msisdn is 2{date :2020-02-25,msisdn:2,date:2020-02-26,msisdn:3}

Comment: There are two dates,`dateHour` and `timestamp`, which one you need to take?

Comment: I wanna take dateHour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like following

```
[
  {
    $unwind: "$detail"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "dHr": {
        $substr: [
          "$dateHour",
          0,
          10
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$dHr",
      msisdn: {
        $addToSet: "$detail.msisdn"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: "$_id",
      count: {
        $size: "$msisdn"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oS_cQ43LdJ6)

Comment: It Worked .. Thanks alott.

Comment: Welcome, but when you post a question, please check that you include all related stuffs. Have a nice day